# Jupyter Notebook freezes at startup via command line on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I cannot seem to start jupyter notebook via the command line after updating my version of python. I just installed 3.7.7, `pip` installed `jupyter`, but when I go to start jupyter via the command line with `jupyter notebook`, it hangs/freezes. I can't `Ctrl-C` the console either, it's fully locked. It was working not 2 hours ago!

I've tried running it with `--debug` but it still hangs after outputting this:

```
[D 19:37:42.193 NotebookApp] Searching ['C:\\WINDOWS\\system32', 'C:\\Users\\[USERNAME]\\.jupyter', 'c:\\program files\\python37\\etc\\jupyter', 'C:\\ProgramData\\jupyter'] for config files
[D 19:37:42.194 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in C:\ProgramData\jupyter
[D 19:37:42.194 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in c:\program files\python37\etc\jupyter
[D 19:37:42.194 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in C:\Users\[USERNAME]\.jupyter
[D 19:37:42.194 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in C:\WINDOWS\system32
[D 19:37:42.195 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in C:\ProgramData\jupyter
[D 19:37:42.195 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in c:\program files\python37\etc\jupyter
[D 19:37:42.195 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in C:\Users\[USERNAME]\.jupyter
[D 19:37:42.196 NotebookApp] Loaded config file: C:\Users\[USERNAME]\.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py
[D 19:37:42.196 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in C:\WINDOWS\system32
[D 19:37:42.197 NotebookApp] Ignoring min_open_files_limit because the limit cannot be adjusted (for example, on Windows)
[D 19:37:42.200 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of jupyter_notebook_config:
        C:\ProgramData\jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.json
[D 19:37:42.201 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of jupyter_notebook_config:
        c:\program files\python37\etc\jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.json
[D 19:37:42.201 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of jupyter_notebook_config:
        C:\Users\Jhuessy\.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.json
```

These files are not in their respective directories and it would seem that I need to either find them or generate them somehow. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Python version: `Python 3.7.7`

```
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
qtconsole        : 4.7.3
ipython          : 7.14.0
ipykernel        : 5.2.1
jupyter client   : 6.1.3
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.6
traitlets        : 4.3.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who might stumble upon this and are at a loss, I fixed it and am about 80% aware of how I did it.

First of all, try opening a command prompt as an administrator and try `ping 127.0.0.1` to see if you can ping your localhost address. When I did it, I would get `General Failure` as a result.

I think that perhaps one of the problems was that jupyter couldn't start because it was trying to host on 127.0.0.1 and was getting denied, hence the hanging after looking for configs. The configs actually had/have nothing to do with the issue, it would seem, since I checked their locations on machines that could run jupyter and they also didn't have configs generated.

I ended up doing the following and at some point the combination worked and I was able to load jupyter again:

- Uninstalling Python via Add/Remove Programs on windows
- Changing the System Path to not point to the Python folders (Python doesn't do this for you with their unistall)
- Checking `Program Files`, `Program Files (x86)`, `AppData`, and `ProgramData` for any and all python related files, and deleting them
- Going into `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\pip` and deleting the `cache` folder
- Going into the Registry and removing the python specific registry keys under `SOFTWARE/Python` in both LOCAL_MACHINE and CURRENT_USER hives
- Opening a command prompt as an Administrator and running:

  - `ipconfig /all`
  - `ipconfig /flushdns`
  - `ipconfig /release`
  - `ipconfig /renew`
- Turning Windows Defender on and off (I don't know if this actually accomplished anything, but it was something I tried between it not working and it working
- Rebooted. Once it came back up, I was able to ping 127.0.0.1 without any issue
- Reinstalled Python 3.7.7 via the web installer (enabled for all users, set system path via the install wizard)
- Opened a command prompt as Administrator and installed jupyter via `pip install jupyter`
- Upgraded pip (not important, but again, it was something that happened between it working and it not working)
- Tested `jupyter --version`
- Crossed fingers and ran `jupyter notebook`
- It started the server right up!

Sorry that this answer isn't as definitive or comprehensive as it should be. I don't know enough about how 127.0.0.1 is held or reserved otherwise it may have been easier to troubleshoot.

If anyone comes across this and knows exactly what it was that was causing this mess, I would love to know!